# ¿Quiero realizar una condicion de un if para saber si mi array tiene dos elementos?

Tags: java, array, condiciones

Quisiera saber que código utilizar para condicionar(por ejemplo en un if) si mi arreglo contiene dos elementos guardados para ejecutar un código u otro. Gracias.
Lo que quisiera hacer es colocar un condicionante que sepa si en el arreglo Elementos tiene únicamente dos datos ingresados para poder ejecutar un codigo  o si tiene mas de dos elementos poder realizar otro codigo

```
   String op,op1;
    double pro,pro1,suma;
    int i;
    op =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de simbolos:");
    pro=Double.parseDouble(op); 
    double Elementos[] = new double [50]; 
      for(  i = 0; i < pro; i ++ ){
           op1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Ingrese la probabilidad del 
   dato Nro "+ ( i+1 ) );
                    pro1 = Double.parseDouble( op1 );
                    Elementos[ i ] = pro1;
                     
    }
        for (int x = 0; x < Elementos.length; x++) {
    for ( i = 0; i < Elementos.length-x-1; i++) {
        if(Elementos[i] < Elementos[i+1]){
            double tmp = Elementos[i+1];
            Elementos[i+1] = Elementos[i];
            Elementos[i] = tmp;
             
        }  
    }
}
txtbinario.setText("");
for(i=0;i<pro;i++){
txtbinario.setText(txtbinario.getText()+"S"+(i+1)+" = 
"+Elementos[i]+"\n");
}
 
}
```

Comment: Hola, con gusto puedo apoyarte pero no haz entrado en contexto, podrias añadir parte de tú código, que haz intentado....

Comment: Ya amigo,se me olvido subir mi código pero ahi esta ese es lo que tengo hasta el momento pero quisiera saber como condicionar el arreglo Elementos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es saber si el array Elementos contiene más de dos valores distintos de 0?

En ese caso lo que debes hacer es recorrer con un for todo el array de Elementos y contar cuántas de esas posiciones contienen un valor distinto que cero.

Puedes utilizar una variable contador 'int contador' e incrementarla cada vez que se cumpla la condición. Y al finalizar el bucle, la variable contador te dirá si han sido más o menos de dos veces.

Por ejemplo:

```
int contador = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Elementos.length; i++) {

   if (Elementos[i] != 0) {

      contador++;

   }

}

if (contador > 2) {

   miFuncion();

} else {

   miOtraFuncion();

}
```